# List Box with multiple entries on Android Tablet shown as drop down

Tags: android, eclipse, gwt

I am working on a web app project using GWT in Eclipse. I have been testing on a few different platforms and noticed on my Android Tablet that the list box on my page shows up as a drop down list instead of a multiple view list box. How can I make it to view the list box in a multiple list view rather than as a drop down view? It pulls up like a multiple list view on a desktop or laptop. Maybe the browser on the tablet only recognizes it as a drop down list? If anyone has any knowledge about this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,

MPH

Comment: I have been able to download mozilla firefox on the android tablet. The list box shows up the same but when you click on it, the browser still treats the list box as a drop down so you can only select one item at a time and the double click feature that is added on the page is completely gone.